# OO Impress incredibly laggy when resizing text

Tags: libreoffice

For some reason whenever I try to resize some text area it takes about a second or two to respond. I didn't experience this when I had 9.10 and, I think, the same version of OO. I have no idea on how to go about figuring out how to fix this problem. Any pointers?

Comment: Could you possibly mention the version of Ubuntu you're using, as well as the version of OO Impress you're using (probly in `Help > About...` in the program)?

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: Ubuntu 10.10. OpenOffice.org 3.2.1 
OOO320m19 (Build:9505)
ooo-build 3.2.1.4, Ubuntu package 1:3.2.1-7ubuntu1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling hardware acceleration fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try Libreoffice (http://www.libreoffice.org/download), its basically the same, but with many tweaks and bug fixes and the development goes on quite fast.

Comment: what are the cons?

Comment: Regarding OpenOffice or LibreOffice?